# dbisql wrong output when ran via Windows batch script

Tags: batch-file, sybase

I am querying a Sybase SQL Anywhere 17 database to get a count from a table, and outputting that count (number) to a txt file. Running in cmd window is fine, but running via batch script gives a different result.

The following works exactly as it should via Windows cmd line:

```
dbisql -datasource=DATABASEHERE -c "UID=USERNAMEHERE;PWD=PASSWORDHERE" SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "DRSYS"."Online" WHERE Status LIKE 'S%'; OUTPUT to OnlineUnreadCount.txt
```

Let's say that output is "190"

However, when running it via batch script, which is:

```
@echo off 
dbisql -datasource=DATABASEHERE -c "UID=USERNAMEHERE;PWD=PASSWORDHERE" SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "DRSYS"."Online" WHERE Status LIKE 'S%'; OUTPUT to OnlineUnreadCount.txt
```

It runs and outputs, but the number in the txt file is "133" instead of the expected "190". What am I doing wrong? I cannot see where the difference is.

Comment: Perhaps the % is being interpreted by batch and is being replaced before it is sent to dbisql. Perhaps % needs to be escaped? Try %% instead?

Comment: @StephenQuan you’re exactly right. That never once crossed my mind, and it should have. Thanks man!